# unable to handle "title" attribute of html control

Tags: html

My html:

```
  <input id="Text2" type="text" title="nepal" name="text" />
```

when I run this.My out put is:
[image]

In real project `title` attr holds imp id's which should hard to change.I just want remove tool tip part means don't want to show `nepal` which is appear comes from `title` attribute.I search a lot but unable to handle it.Any suggestion.Thanks.

Comment: what does "id's which should hard to change" mean ? Please elaborate your question.. It is obvious that title attribute gives the tool tip..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent the tooltip from appearing by removing the attribute whenever the mouse is over it. This is easy to achieve in jQuery.

```
var titleAttribute;

$('#Text2').hover(function() {
    titleAttribute = $(this).attr("title");
    $(this).attr("title", "");
}, function() {
    $(this).attr("title", titleAttribute);
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot.You caught my real problem and give me a correct solution.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't commandeer built-in attributes for your own use. The title attribute is what makes that tooltip appear. Get rid of it, and instead, use a [custom data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/):

```
<input id="Text2" type="text" data-imp-id="nepal" name="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing tool tip: remove the `title` attribute and the tool tip wont appear. You also have the `rel` attribute which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand Why do you want to add TITLE tag if you dont need the tooltip.

Thus there can be 2 solutions:
1) Remove the title tag as if does not hold any importance in your code.
2) If you want to show a tool tip and dont want to show nepal change it with the context of you input box for which title tags are generally used.
http://www.searchenginejournal.com/how-to-use-link-title-attribute-correctly/7687/